# Getting properties of Query Find

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

In prototyping a login functionality to my ember app, I am using the route to make a query to the store based on a given username. If that username is not found, my API returns an object with a message property. Here is that route:

```
App.LoginRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    actions: {
        getUsername: function(username){
            this.store.find('user', {username: username}).then(function(user){
            var eid = user.get('eid');
            console.log(eid);
            if (eid) {
                self.controller.send('transition', "index");
                }
            else {
                self.controller.set('model', "Oops! That's not right.");}
                });
            }
    }
});`
```

If the username exists in the databse, the API will send back user object. It loads into the store just fine if the username exists, I can see the record under Data in Ember Inspector. However, I cannot figure out how to get the properties of that user object.

In the `.then` I am passing the returned information, and attempting to call `.get` on that, but that always returns undefined.

What is the proper way to get the properties of whatever is returned from a `store.find('store', {query})`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

find by query returns a collection.

```
this.store.find('user', {username: username}).then(function(userCollection){
  // this would be the user if it existed
  var user = userCollection.get('firstObject');
  self.controller.send('transition', "index");
});
```

You probably should be returning a 404 error code instead of a valid response when the user doesn't exist, then hit the failure portion of the promise.

```
this.store.find('user', {username: username}).then(function(userCollection){
  // this would be the user if it existed
  var user = userCollection.get('firstObject');
  self.controller.send('transition', "index");
}, function(){
  // failure happened
  self.controller.set('model', "Oops! That's not right.");}
});
```

Comment: Thank you for correcting my understanding on what the find query returns! I have been wrestling with that for a couple days now. Your solution worked exactly as I need it to. Thank you!

Comment: When you get confused on what's being returned, you can always use `.toString()` to tell you what type of model is being returned. In Kingpin2k's example, in the `.then()` you'd do `console.log( userCollection.toString() )` which will tell you this is a collection.

Comment: Any tips for why what is returned has no content? I can't get anything out of that. I would like to be able to know the details of what was returned, but `userCollection.get('firstObject')` returns undefined.

Comment: Looks like it was a problem with my data on the backend, got it all figured out. Thanks!